# What's the biggest caps reward from Mysterious Stranger?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've received 2460 caps accompanied by caps raining on my whole screen.

But what is the maximum?

Comment: Anecdote rather than answer; I received 4,993 - I caught him twice in a row (I only received 128 caps the first time).

Comment: I wonder if the reward can go above five thousand caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got 4975 caps.

5000 caps is probably the maximum.

The payoff may be based on the size of your vault, how fast you find the stranger or may just be random.

Comment: It is most likely random. I got him twice in a row, instantly clicked him the first time: 120 something. Had to search a bit the second time: 2k.

Answer (score 0):

I got around 6100 last night. I swear it's like if I see him and wait until right before he disappears, he drops more. As I always get the 1000+ cap drops whenever I find him at what feels like the last second... Although I'm sure it's random.